# Undefined offset: 0 using array_push

Tags: php

I need help decipher an error message. The error happens very rarely and I'm not sure how to reproduce it. The error message says line 188 makes an exception but I'm assuming its really line 189? What could prompt this error message? (That is, what could be in $response that makes it impossible to add?)

```
$responses = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $nr; $i++) {
187     $response = $mySession->get($userid, $uid, 'results'.$i);
188     if(!empty($response))
189         array_push($responses, $response);
    }


Error message: production.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0 in [...]/controller.php:188
```

EDIT:

> Stack trace: 0 /.../app/Http/Controllers/Step_1_Controller.php(188):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8,
>   'Undefined offse...', '/home/.../...', 188, Array)
>
> 1 [internal function]:
>   App\Http\Controllers\Step_1_Controller->processMultiSearch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ...

Comment: That error doesn't make any sense on either line.

Comment: Are you sure error is in this file ? not an other controller ?

Comment: I'll try to edit the question to include the stack trace. Looks to me the error happens there.